# Variadic template calling assert()

Tags: c++, templates, assert

I have this code:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define MY_VERY_SPECIAL_ASSERT(x, ...) assert(x && __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define MY_VERY_SPECIAL_ASSERT(x, ...)
#endif
```

which does precisely what it's supposed to. But, in an effort to continue learning forevermore, I'm trying to abide by the `constexpr` variadic template guideline from the core-cpp set.

I've tried a few permutations, but this one seems the most "correct"

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
template<typename T>
constexpr void MY_VERY_SPECIAL_ASSERT(T x, const std::string &msg) {
    assert(x && msg);
}
#else
template<typename T>
constexpr void MY_VERY_SPECIAL_ASSERT(T x, const std::string &msg) { }
#endif
```

But of course, it doesn't want to compile. Specifically, there's no logical-and overload for "T" and string, which kind of makes sense. You'd think it'd just always return true, right?

Anyway, if anyone has any pointers here, I'm happy to learn more about templating. =)

Comment: No idea what the code *should* do! Do you want to check for a condition and abort execution but output a message before?

Comment: That's it. I've seen `assert([test] && "msg")` used often times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is a `bool`, namely it is the result of evaluating the expression `E1` with

```cpp
static_cast<decltype (E1)> (false) != E1;
```

You're getting the error because `std::string` has no implicit conversion to `bool`.

```cpp
constexpr void MY_VERY_SPECIAL_ASSERT(T x, const std::string &msg) {
    // assert(x && static_cast<bool>(msg)); // won't work
    assert(x && msg.empty()); // Should work. The string won't be displayed when an assertion fails, though.
}
```

But this wouldn't do what one could think it would, anyway.

```cpp
assert(x && msg);
```

Will always result in the message "Assertion failed: x && msg" being displayed.
You can use this instead:

```cpp
assert ( false or !"message" );

#ifndef _DEBUG
# define SPECIAL_ASSERT(...) ()
#else
# define SPECIAL_ASSERT(COND, MSG) (assert(COND or! MSG))
#endif


SPECIAL_ASSERT( 1 == 0, "One isn't zero." );
```

Comment: Spectacular. Thank you.